# What should I do if an array needs to transfer by using the symfony form builder

Tags: php, symfony

In my cookbook entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")  //Here needs an array
 */
 protected $foods;
```

I built a form type called 'CookbookType' like this:

```
class CookbookType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
      $builder
        ->add(
           'foods','collection',['allow_add' => true,'by_reference' => false,'type' => 'eating_foods']
        )
        ->add('confirm','submit',['label' => '提交']);
   }
}
```

and a 'FoodsType'

```
class FoodsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('food','text')
            ->add('weight','text');
    }
}
```

When i submit this form, i got this error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Alpha\RecipeBundle\Entity\Cookbook::addFood() must be of the type array, object given
```

So, what can be done if i want to solve the problem by "a symfony's way" ?

Comment: Do you have a Food entity defined?  What does Cookbook::addFood look like?  The error message indicates that addFood is expecting an array instead of a Food object?